# How to Suspend Child Task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I created two tasks `task_1` and `task_2` and set dependency. I want to run root task and suspend child task.
But getting below error

```
alter task task_2 suspend ;
091421 (22000): Unable to update graph with root task TESTDB.PUBLIC.TASK_1 since that root task is not suspended.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to suspend the root task, suspend the child task and resume the root task again

See more information here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-task.html

„The root task in a tree of tasks must be suspended before any task in the tree is modified, a child task is suspended or resumed“